# How to handle concatenate with empty matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, concatenation

I have three matrices `A,B,C`, they all have the same amount of rows.
I want to create a new matrix D that is the concatenation of A,B,C with respect to columns.

This is my very simple code

```
A = numpy.concatenate((A, numpy.concatenate((B, C), axis=1))), axis=1)
```

When all the matrices exist, it's fine and works as expected.

But sometimes its possible that I will only have A, or only B C etc. Sometimes one or two may be empty. In these cases, the program will fail.

What's the best and most code efficient way to handle this? if B for example does not exist, we will have that `B = None`

Comment: I'm an agent of simplicity. I know I can write a million if cases, but rather not if python has a built in trick that can help me.

Comment: you could create an array of empty/ones or zeros of the desired shape and just fill the axis with the values of A, B and/or C that you have available at that time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can combine your two calls to `concatenate`:

```
result = numpy.concatenate((A, B, C), axis=1)
```

Two options then - either filter out the `None`s:

```
arrs = [a for a in (A, B, C) if a is not None]
result = numpy.concatenate(arrs, axis=1)
```

Or better yet, actually use "empty" arrays, rather than passing `None`:

```
A = np.random.randn(3, 5)  # your actual data
B = np.zeros((3, 0))  # set to something with the same height as A, not None
C = np.zeros((3, 0))  # still 3 rows, but each row is empty
result = numpy.concatenate((A, B, C), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is a more elegant version but you can use sequence of "if":

```
if not A is None and not B is None and not C is None:
    X = numpy.concatenate((A, numpy.concatenate((B, C), axis=1)), axis=1)
elif A is None:
    if not B is None and not C is None:
        X = numpy.concatenate((B, C), axis=1)   
    elif B is None:
        X = C
    else:
        X = B
elif B is None:
    if not A is None and not C is None:
        X = numpy.concatenate((A, C), axis=1)   
    elif A is None:
        X = C
    else:
        X = A
elif C is None:
    if not A is None and not B is None:
        X = numpy.concatenate((A, B), axis=1)   
    elif A is None:
        X = B
    else:
        X = A
else:
    X = None
```

I hope i help you, good work

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it as follows:

- Initialize three variables a, b and c corresponding to A, B and C
  matrices and set them to zero.
- Now, wherever the assignment of A, B
  and C is taking place, change the value of the variables a, b and c
  respectively.
- After all the assignments, you will get to know which
  one is None using a,b and c.